# U.S. Army Veteran Seeking Freelance Service Provider for Equity Shares for Start-Up Corporation

Tags: freelance-websites

I am a U.S. Armed Forces Veteran searching for avenues and sites that offer Freelance workers the opertunity to provide services for equity in order to further my business. The company Loom out of Austin, TX advertised for this in aritcles on the subject no longer exists apparently, or I can't find them rather, only where they once existed amd raised funds for their company. There is no talk of other platforms I have found and the mainstream Freelancer sites specifically disallow for equity contracts or relationships outside of the platform when origionally formed on their platform. Does anyone know where that could be found? The colleges are still shut down as well are business conventions in the city, so finding local cofounders is difficult.

Comment: 1) What does being a Veteran have to do with this?? I mean, thanks for the service, but using it here *seems* like you want to gain favor due to it. and B) "Equity Shares" equates to 0 dollars in *many* cases. In fact, I'd wager ALL freelancers are approached with this type of offer regularly. If you actually *believe* in your business, hire someone and *pay them*. - in short, [**see here**](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/917/client-wants-to-pay-a-percentage-of-revenue-generated-by-website/923#923)

Comment: Any equity stake could be a bonus or addition to payment, but not the *only* form of return. This is the reason you *can't* find web sites offering such structures. They are *commonly* used to, well, take advantage of freelancers. I'm not saying that is your intention -- but look at it from the freelancers perspective.. they put in all the necessary work.. and MIGHT earn *nothing* because your other business model areas are poor or ill-conceived.

Comment: Why the vote-to-close? I agree that the 'US veteran' part is irrelevant - but the question and comment-answer seem reasonable to me

Comment: I labeled it with U.S. Veteran in attempt to find persons understanding of a Veterans sense of duty, mission-oriented drive, and law abiding nature. Second I can not at this time have payroll employees as I do not have that amount of funding. I live on government subsidy and blue collar work. Loans require payments I do not have and I was not born to a middle class level inheritence. Citizen is my inheritence. Feedback from VC's and others state a need for Cofounder members, not myself solemente. This is my first using this forum. My apologies for offenses interpreted. Thank you for any reply.

Comment: Then you do not have the necessary tools to create a business.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.

Unfortunately, you won't hear many friendly voices about your request, and I am not exempt. First of all, why would we care about you being a veteran? How does that qualify you as a businessman?

Then: Get a loan from a bank to pay the work you are asking for. **Banks do loans, freelancers do paid work.** Sorry if that sounds rush, but there is a reason most freelancing sites ban such proposals: We hate those. We get hundreds of those, and never accept one.

If banks are no option: Write a good - a great - business plan, and search for so-called business angels. They will provide the funds to hire a freelancer.

You simply mixed financing and getting-it-done up. Those are two separate jobs.